# How to fix PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xxx/xxx/yaf.so'?

Tags: php

[26-Nov-2021 21:49:17 Asia/Shanghai] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.40/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/yaf.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.40/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/yaf.so, 0x0009): tried: '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.40/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/yaf.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/yaf.so' (no such file) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Sounds like you've tried to run an incompatible version of MAMP. Also, be warned that PHP 5.6.40 is pretty outdated - did you try running your project with a more recent version of MAMP?

Comment: Is an incompatible architecture: Trying to load the yaf.so library, but it's compiled for arm64, instead of x86_64, which is the architecture of the server machine. You need version for x86_64.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP 
Thank you, MacbookAir2020's M1 chip architecture is arm64, so I need to use x86_64 architecture Macbook development?

Comment: Oh, then the error message is advicing that arm64 was found, but x86_64 is needed. So, I guess you can't use that library in your M1.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP I see, I wish you all the best in your life! Blessings from china

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the incorrect version for your PHP Version.
if this is Yet Another Framework
You can only use this on the version of PHP is created for.
for example if your PHP Version is 5.3
You would need a yaf.so to match PHP 5.3

Looking on there GIT this is a 5.2 build, so your PHP Version needs to match this.

Personally i would ditch the 5.3 you are running and install 7.0.
5.3 is very dated, pointless developing anything based on this.

When you have the right version, Place this inside your ext folder in PHP.
Edit your PHP.ini file
add in:

```
extension=yaf.so
```

Ensure your extension_dir is configured correctly too:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

your yaf should be in the same folder as the extension dir, just ensure extension is built for the PHP version you are using, they are not cross compatible

Comment: Thank you, yaf.so matches the version of PHP;
This problem does not occur when I use a MacBook with an intel processor.